# Get first row with jQuery on a specific HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML:

```
<p class="myclass">

<span class="generalclass">text1</span>
<span>text2</span>
<span>text3</span>
</p>

<p class="myclass">

<span class="generalclass">text1</span>
<span>text2</span>
<span>text3</span>
</p>
```

and each of the other 3 `<p>` tags are identical.

This my jQuery Code:

```
var promo = $('[class^="myclass"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
    //I try something like return $(this).children.text(':first') but NOT Work
}).get();
let promo1 = promo[0];
let promo2 = promo[1];
let promo3 = promo[2];
```

Results:
promo1 = text1
text2
text3

How can I get the text from only `<span>` / ROW 1 and not the other span tag content?

tks

Comment: You are selecting the `<p>` element, so the map doesn't iterate over each `<span>`. You'll need to either use two loops, or a more specific selector (depending on what you want) to get the text from each span.

Comment: What output are you expecting here? Just `text1` from the first row, or `text1 text1` from the first row of ***each*** `p`?

Comment: Just text1 from the first row Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0):

```js
var promo = $('[class^="myclass"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).children(":first").html();
}).get();
let promo1 = promo[0];
let promo2 = promo[1];
let promo3 = promo[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code to get the value from the first `<span>`

```
var promo = $('[class^="myclass"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).find("span:first-of-type").text();
}).get();
```

Comment: Tks for answer. it worked in part.
The code get the all <span> tags:

<p class="myclass">
<img src="/iconWhite_Promotion.svg">
Verão 2022
<span class="t-tip">
<span class="t-tip__text">
<span class="font-weight-bold">Verão 2022</span>
<br>
<br>
<span>Desconto:</span> 1 Noite
<br>
<br>
<span>Condições:</span>
Ao escolher o Tarifário: Melhor Tarifa Disponível. Para reservas com um mínimo de 3 noite(s).
</span>
</span>
</p>
<span class="incentive_value">1 Noite</span>
</span>


I need just the part: Verão 2022Desconto: 1 Noite